# Parse-ing Date from JSON D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to parse this date using the D3.js libary.

```
2013-07-07 00:06:02.480270
```

I have tried so many variation but it always returns null
For example :

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L").parse;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+0000").parse;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
```

It´s endless trial and error.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting), D3 expects the milliseconds to be three digits at most. You will either have to cut off the last three digits of your string or use something else to parse it.

Comment: Just sliced off the last three and it worked. Thanks. 
var str = d.date;
d.date = parseDate( str.substring(0, str.length - 3) );